# How to implement the conversion from object to integer and back again to object when creating combinatorial sets

Tags: c#

I must create combinatorial sets of 3 kinds:

1. permutations
2. partial permutations
3. combinations

It is not a homework. I am on pension and I am trying to keep busy. I learned C# more or less and now I am endeavoring to learn the best practices.

The process is as follows:
   the input is a list of items (objects) out of which the combinatorial sets must be generated. The kind of objects is not of consequence, as I only use the number of items (`list.Count = n`).
I create a list of integers, starting from `1` and up to `n`.
I also create a Dictionary which defines the correspondence between each integer in the list of integers and the corresponding object whose representative the integer is (the key in the dictionary).
The list of integers is sent as argument to the appropriate method (along with another integer `k` - the number of items in each partial permutation set or combination, in case of combinations or partial permutations), in order the required kind of combinatorial sets to be created. I already have these methods.
The output of the method is a list of lists of integers. Each list of integers is a combinatorial set.
By means of the correspondence dictionary, this list of lists of integers is converted into a list of lists of objects in which each list is a combinatorial set, but now not of integers but of the original items. I do this for each specific method, according to the required type of combinatorial set. 
I wonder whether there is a more correct way to do this: whatever the kind of combinatorial set, the conversion from object to integer and then back from integer to object must be performed.

In order to explain, I will use Wyck's example:

Suppose I must generate permutation sets of 3 items (objects):

new List() { objA, objB, objC };
I create a list of integers: new List() { 1, 2, 3 };

The integer output is: list of permutations: {{1,2,3}, {1,3,2}, {2,1,3}, {2,3,1}, {3,1,2}, {3,2,1}}

I now create the objects output, by using the correspondence dictionary:

1 -> objA

2 -> objB

3 -> objC

so the output is:

new List() { {objA, objB, objC}, {objA, objC, objB}, ..., {objC, objB, objA} };

Now next time I must create combinations of the same 3 objects in sets of 2.
The same list of 3 integers is passed to another method that creates a list of integer lists, where each list is a combination of 3 integers taken 2 at a time.

The output is: list of combinations: { {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3} };

And now again I have to convert this list of lists of integers into a list of lists of object:

new List() { {objA, objB}, {objA, objC}, {objB, objC} };

I am not asking for code. Rather, for the way to think and maybe the kind of pattern to use (interface for instance), but also more importantly, how to implement it (not code but explanation, as clear and detailed as possible as of how to get the preliminary step of forming the list of integers and passing it to the correct method and the final step of converting the list of lists of integers into a list of lists of objects in an automated way).
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I must say it is a bit hard to follow exactly what you are trying to achieve, can you provide the methods you already have, and some pseudo-code? Have you done any research - if so could you provide what you have tried so far?

Comment: Wow, for a post that is full of coherent sentences, this is really hard to follow.  I think it's because there's no paragraph structure, no supporting examples, and no sentence ending in a question mark.  It's also tagged C# but you specifically neither provide code nor ask for code in return.  Also "better way" is highly subjective and will draw opinionated answers.  You're using an indirect index pattern - that seems fine.

Comment: Input: `new List<object>() { objA, objB, objC }`  output: list of permutations: `{{1,2,3}, {1,3,2}, {2,1,3}, {2,3,1}, {3,1,2}, {3,2,1}}`.  Right so far?  (At least...for the base case, ignoring `k` for now)

Comment: Are you asking how to convert `{3,1,2}` into `{ objC, objA, objB }`?  Or are you asking something much more general like: should you be using integers at all?

Comment: @WyckThank you for the interest. The example you gave is exactly correct. Now I convert the n! = 3! = 6 permutation sets of integers cited by you into 6 permutation sets of objects: {objA, objB, objC}, {objA, objC, objB}, ..., {objC, objB, objA}. The question is whether there is a shorter way, or I have to do this every time "by hand" when I call one of the methods; this time I called the permutations method, next time I may need combinations and so on. Is there a way to call any one of these methods and to perform these conversions automatically every time? (question mark applied).

Answer (score 0):

I finally worked it out.
I initially designed the solution in the following way:
There is a main class that receives through its constructor or elicits from the user the list of items to generate the combinatorial sets out of.
For each kind of combinatorial sets there is a class that generates them.
This class:
1. receives through its constructor the list of n items (objects of type T) to generate 
   the respective type of combinatorial set.
2. creates a list of integers from 1 through n (the number of items in the list of items).
3. populates a Dictionary correspondenceDictionary between each integer in the 
   list of integers and the corresponding item (object T).
4. generates the list of lists of sets of combinatorial sets with integers from the list 
   of integers.
5. populates the list of lists of lists of items (objects of type T), using the 
   correspondenceDictionary, which is returned to the main list.
After some thought I arrived to the conclusion that the conversions do not have to be performed by the respective classes, but can be done in the main class:
1. the creation of the list of integers from 1 through n.
2. this list of integers is passed to the appropriate class for generation of the 
   respective type of combinatorial sets (of integers).
3. the list of lists of integers is then used to create the list of lists of items 
   (objects) by means of the correspondenceDictionary which is created in the main class.

In addition, I noticed that most of the algorithms that generate combinatorial sets use only the indices of the list (or array) of items passed to them, so actually it is not necessary at all to convert the object to integers and back.
The classes that generate the combinatorial sets can be generic classes of type T and perform the combinatorial sets generation directly on them.
There is one constraint:
some algorithms (those that create combinatorial sets in which the items' order is relevant - permutations and partial permutations) must be able to compare two items. Therefore the type T must implement the interface IComparable.
If that is not the case, the solution with conversion to integers and back to objects may be used.
Conversely, a comparer for the respective object can be prepared and passed to the appropriate class.